# Disable Smart Copy/Paste globally

Tags: finder, copy-paste, autocorrect

If I copy a word and paste it at the beginning of a filename in Finder, a space it automatically added with it. For example, if I copy the word `fruit` and attempt to paste it at the beginning of a filename `basket`, I would get `fruit basket` instead of `fruitbasket` (notice the automatically-added space).

I can disable this feature in Safari and TextEdit, but the setting appears to be missing in Finder. Furthermore, as I never use this feature, I would much prefer for it to be disabled globally. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have confused copying a word and copying the letters of a word.

Copying a *word* (double click on a word, then command-C) does include a trailing space which is included when you paste in a filename.  In some apps copying a word this way also includes a leading space.

But copying the *letters of a word* (click and drag over the word, then command-C) does not include the trailing space. A paste in a filename then behaves as you want.

I realise this does not explicitly answer your question, but I hope it clarifies copying words.

Comment: That does help clear things up a bit. I usually double-click to highlight words. Indeed, highlighting the letters of a word and pasting them does not produce a trailing space. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting followup, I found out that this does not affect Terminal, so there has to be something special Finder is seeing. Maybe (just a theory), along with the copied word, a variable like `copiedAsWord=true` is set, and Finder checks for this and adds a space, whereas Terminal ignores the variable entirely.

Comment: @leetbacoon I hadn't noticed that before. I suspect that it is something special that Terminal does as other apps respect the trailing space on words.